# thread pool implementation - am i doing it right?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I’m new to multithreading.
I’m having difficulties understanding what is wrong with my implemantation, and why every implementation I see is using synchronized blocks and notifys.
The running seems ok so i can’t point to what exactly is not good but I assume there are some multithreading principles I'm not following.

This is the code:

```
public class Threads {
static Queue<MyThread> queue = new LinkedList<>();
static Thread[] threadsArr = new Thread[10];

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Threads t = new Threads();
    t.startArr();
    t.startProcess();
}
void startArr(){
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        threadsArr[i] = new Thread(new MyThread(i));
    }
}
void startProcess(){

    for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
        queue.add(new MyThread(i));
    }
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
        int insertPlace = 0;
        boolean isFull = true;
        while (isFull){
            for (int j=0;j<10;j++){
                if (!threadsArr[j].isAlive()){
                    insertPlace = j;
                    isFull = false;
                }
            }
        }
        threadsArr[insertPlace] = new Thread(new MyThread(i));
        threadsArr[insertPlace].start();
    }
}
```

}

and the MyThread class:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
int threadNumber;
public MyThread(int threadNumber){
    this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(threadNumber + " started.");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(threadNumber + " finished.");

}
```

}

thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to write your own thread pool? Java already has [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: It's a bad idea to write a thread pool if you don't really understand threading.

Comment: i was given this task in a job interview. so im trying to improve for the next interviews. also im trying to understand the basics of multi threading.

Comment: The main issue in your code is that it is not a thread pool. How can I as a client utilize a thread from the pool and return it back to it when I don't need it any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you missed the role of a "ThreadPoolExecutor". Basically, the user that uses your class wants to be able to call an "execute(Runnable run)" method, knowing that your Threads class will handle the execution in the process it is allowed to create.
You should rework the API of your class and provide this kind of method (see real ThreadPoolExecutor for instance http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Second, if you are training for a job interview, try to write cleaner and more flexible code by not having constant like "10" all around the class. This should be an attribute provided by the user of your class (in the constructor), specifying how many threads at once he wants to allow (again see the real ThreadPoolExecutor).

Finally I am no expert in implementing ThreadPoolExecutors, but you could consider using a BlockingQueue (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) which support, i quote, "operations that wait for the queue to become non-empty when retrieving an element". This could be useful for waiting for a Thread to be available, rather to do it yourself. But I guess there are better answers.

Good luck,

Mathias